# Send a message from a celery background task to the browser with Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a long running task running on Celery. When it is done, I want to send a message to the browser that will simply instruct it to refresh the page. To do that, I want to use channels V2.

It's not clear from the docs how to achieve that.

This is what I have in my background task, but I'm not sure how to set up the Consumer

```
@shared_task
def my_task():
    time.sleep(5)
    Channel('my-background-task').send({"refresh": True})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ReloadConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.group_name = self.scope['user']
        print(self.group_name)  # use this for debugging not sure what the scope returns

        # Join group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def reload_page(self, event):
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'reload': True
        }))
        self.disconnect()
```

Then when your celery task is completed you send a reload_page message to the relevant group.

```
@shared_task
def my_task():
    ... do your task ...
    group_name = get_user_name()  # Find out way to get same as what is printed on connect()

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    # Trigger reload message sent to group
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {'type': 'reload_page'}
    )
```

Once you can successfully create a group for the user when they start the celery task, then send a message to the user's group on completion it's as simple as adding this script:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue using the same solution with the decorator "app.task".
I change the decorator to "shared_task" and everything is working now. If someone else has this issue

Comment: This does not work for me. The "async_to_sync" part does not seem to have any effect. I am using Django 2.2.8, celery 4.4.1 and channels 2.4.0

Comment: @unicorn do you have a method in your consumer called `reload_page`? If so put a print in there to see if it's firing.

Comment: @bdoubleu "async_to_sync" part isn't working for me too. It's working from console but not from the celery task to consumer. Got any suggestions?